# Confusion about what values are actually being computed in assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly

I have read answers to similar questions as mine on stack-overflow, but I'm still confused on whats actually happening "under the hood" between these two statements, so I can better understand how data is used in other functions.

---

## Supposed we have theoretical registers 'a' and 'b':

[image]

we have the instruction: "addq a, b" which translates to b = a + b or b += a.

Does this mean "set the register value of b equal to the sum of the register value of b plus the register value of a"

Resulting in register 'b's value changing from 5 to 5 + 7 = 12.

OR

Does this mean "set the register value of b equal to the sum of the register ADDRESS of b plus the register ADDRESS of a"

Resulting in register 'b's value changing from 5 to 0x1 + 0x2 = 0x3.

I'm assuming the the first answer is correct, but then what is the difference between the first statement and this statement: "addq (a), b"?

My interpretation of this statement is "set the register value of b equal to (the dereferenced value of register a which equals the contents of a which equals the register value of a) plus the register value of b.

Resulting in register 'b's value changing from 5 to 5 + 7 = 12. But B isn't dereferenced, so shouldn't this mean "set the register ADDRESS of b equal to (the dereferenced value of register a which equals the contents of a which equals the register VALUE of a) plus the register VALUE of b?

But then this doesn't seem consistent to me either because b isn't dereferenced so wouldn't it be setting the register ADDRESS of b equal the the register VALUE of a plus the register ADDRESS of b?

Maybe the destination argument is implicitly dereferenced; maybe whether its the address or value read depends on the type of function call; maybe the src (address or value) is always written to the destination registers value, so the dereference is either illegal or implied as well?

---

Cleary, I have some concept backwards and/or incorrect, **what is the correct interpretation?**

**Or and are there edge cases or rules that I am not aware of pertaining to which function arguments can be dereferenced or are implicitly dereferenced or how this might change depending on the operation?**

Comment: Registers don't have memory addresses; that table looks misleading unless they just mean those are the register numbers for encoding into machine code.  A register can *hold* a pointer (whose value is a memory address); you can dereference a register.  But you can't take its address.  (e.g. in C, you can't use `&` on `register int foo`.)

Comment: what instruction set is this?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot know if you don't indicate the assembly language and flavor.

However, it is custom to indicate memory references using []'s or ()'s notation.

Without these brackets, we might presume mere register updates.

Brackets are not necessary but are typically indicative of memory references, and their absence of simple register-to-register references.